Suppress null check in response object in latest version of NSwag.MSBuild 14.7.0
We have POST endpoints in REST API project that return null response  when 200 status code.
Recently when we regenerated clients using v14.7.0 version of NSwagMSBuild, we see that it has added additional null checks on response object because of which our tests now failing.
Is there a way to configure to not generate this new null checks for specific (or all) endpoints in latest version of NSwagMsbuild?
Here is the document generation part of my NSwag.json.
"defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null" already (found in another forum)
   "runtime": "Net80",
   "defaultVariables": "Configuration=Release,OutDir=bin/Release/net8.0/,HomeDir=%USERPROFILE%",
   "documentGenerator": {
   "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
    "project": "APIProj.AppServices.csproj",
    "controllerNames": [],
    "isAspNetCore": true,
    "resolveJsonOptions": false,
    "defaultUrlTemplate": "api/{controller}/{id?}",
    "addMissingPathParameters": false,
    "includedVersions": null,
    "defaultPropertyNameHandling": "CamelCase",
    "defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
    "defaultDictionaryValueReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
    "defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
    "defaultEnumHandling": "Integer",
    "flattenInheritanceHierarchy": false,
    "generateKnownTypes": true,
    "generateEnumMappingDescription": false,
    "generateXmlObjects": false,
    "generateAbstractProperties": false,
    "generateAbstractSchemas": true,
    "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false,
    "allowReferencesWithProperties": false,
    "excludedTypeNames": [],
    "serviceHost": null,
    "serviceBasePath": null,
    "serviceSchemes": [],
    "infoTitle": "My Title",
    "infoDescription": null,
    "infoVersion": "1.0.0",
    "documentTemplate": null,
    "documentProcessorTypes": [],
    "operationProcessorTypes": [],
    "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
    "schemaNameGeneratorType": null,
    "contractResolverType": null,
    "serializerSettingsType": null,
    "useDocumentProvider": true,
    "documentName": "v1",
    "aspNetCoreEnvironment": null,
    "createWebHostBuilderMethod": null,
    "startupType": null,
    "allowNullableBodyParameters": true,
    "output": null,
    "outputType": "Swagger2",
    "newLineBehavior": "Auto",
    "assemblyPaths": [],
    "assemblyConfig": null,
    "referencePaths": [
      "$(HomeDir)/.nuget/packages"
    ],
    "validateEnums": false,
    "generateEnums": false,
    "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
    "configuration": "$(Configuration)",
    "runtime": null,
    "targetFramework": null,
    "noBuild": true,
    "msBuildOutputPath": null,
    "verbose": true,
    "workingDirectory": null,
    "requireParametersWithoutDefault": false,
    "apiGroupNames": null,
    "useNuGetCache": false
    }
   },


Is there any other parameter to set?
I have checked the RicoSuter/NSwagPublic discussuin forum for the answer but could not get any.
